# Virtual environment management for python.el without changing the general PATH variable in Emacs

Tags: python, shell, path, virtualenv

I try to use [virtualenvwrapper.el](https://github.com/porterjamesj/virtualenvwrapper.el) with the build-in `python.el` and my virtual environments in a `./.venv` directory inside each project.

Because all virtual envs have the same name `.venv` I cannot make a list of all venvs  in `venv-location`. What I do instead is, when I want to work in a particular environment (say `~/my/project/.venv`), I set:

```
(setq venv-location (list "~/my/project/.venv"))
(venv-workon (venv-dir-to-name "~/my/project/.venv")))
```

This works as expected for instantiating the inferior Python process via `M-x run-python`: This process runs in the virtual env  `~/my/project/.venv`.

However because `venv-workon` seems to change Emacs' general PATH variable, normal swells (started with M-x shell`) are affected too: They all get the virtual env`~/my/project/.venv`. But I do not want this for my normal shells.

***How can I manage my Python virtual environments for `python.el`'s Python processes , but not for shell and all other processes?*** Do other libraries (like `pyenv`) handle this as I want it?(*)

---

(*) I had tried [pyvenv](http://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv) earlier and if I remember it right I had the same issue: Normal shell get thesame virtual env as my python project.

Comment: I have never used a virtual environment wrapper ....  I have, however, set the `process-environment` on a buffer-local basis and modified the path for just the current buffer, e.g., an `eshell` buffer; or, to generate a LaTeX PDF file from a *.tex buffer, etc.  E.g., `(set (make-local-variable 'process-environment) (mapcar 'concat process-environment))` and `(setenv "PATH" (concat "/absolute/path/to/folder/of/executables:" (getenv "PATH")))` -- note the colon ...

Comment: @lawlist That looks like a pretty cool idea! I wasn't aware that you can make the `process-environment` buffer-local. Not sure though how to integrate this with python.el/virtualenvwrapper.el...

Comment: I have not attempted to tweak or fix virtual environment wrapper, but I thought perhaps providing an example of how to create a subprocess with a custom/temporary PATH (that does *not* permanently alter/clobber the global `process-environment`) might help some:  https://gist.github.com/lawlist/6b9da6e3199e2a5ebf581655b3c0ba4c